# Horror movie with an alien tentacle coming out of a man's mouth, female possession, and a man trying to escape by car

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

So I was surfing on Youtube and came upon this video [[content warning: rape](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_h8Ze1AaYAs)]. It's age-restricted so a simple process to bypass the security measure might be needed to view.

To summarize, a woman in the video is tackled by a tall, bearded man onto a bed and a tentacle comes out of the man's mouth to possess? the woman by inserting itself into the woman's vagina. Another man (presumably the woman's friend) grabs a gun to investigate what's going on upstairs. The attacker is decapitated (not sure how) and eventually, the two characters escape by car but the woman is possessed and turns into a zombie-like being that makes a loud shrilling noise.

The characters in the film speak English so I don't think it's a foreign film. I've spent the last 2-3 hours trying to look for clues but have finally given up. Would anyone happen to know where this video is from? Much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is [Almost Human](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYfsQOmMpB4) [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2325517/)

Plot

> Mark Fisher disappeared from his home in a brilliant flash of blue
> light almost 2 years ago. His friend Seth Hampton was the last to see
> him alive. Now a string of grisly, violent murders leads Seth to
> believe that Mark is back, and something evil is inside of him.